# Link element - JS onclick event not raised / clickElement doesn't work (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

On the website I'm automating there's a link 'disguised' as an icon. When clicked on by a user, either a file Save/Open windows prompt pops up or a file is downloaded depending on the browser settings.

When I tried to simulate clicking on this element, neither PerformClick nor RaiseEvent("onclick") had any effect though no exception was thrown during execution. I am 100% sure correct element is found because this element is unique.

The said element has a structure such as this:

```
<a id="downloadCsv" class = "..." href="#" onclick=".."> [event]

 <span class="icon">< /span>

</a>
```

Click event is on of the events attached to that element.

Why are these methods not working?

Comment: Create [mre] with all relevant code you talk about. Use snippet by pressing <> button in editor.

Comment: Also read: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/programmatically-opening-a-file-dialog-with-javascript

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share any code due to security reasons. I see will have to work on a handler of a user-initiated event.

Comment: No code, no-help, that's kind of SO rule... No one will take guess or should.